# Delete rows from table when the result are not in a csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have this code to insert values from a csv file. Some values are updated when the row already exist at the database. Just how I want it to be.

```
INSERT INTO test_table (`id`,`order_id`,`quantity`,`price`,`order_date`,`shipping_date`)
                    VALUES ('$orderId', '$quantity', '$price', '$orderDate', '$shippingDate')
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `order_date` = '$orderDate', `shipping_date` = '$shippingDate'"
```

But when the row is not at the csv it must be deleted from the database.
For example:

csv file:

```
order_id  quantity price order_date shipping_date
1          10      1.00  2016-10-5  2016-10-6
```

I run the script and the result from the csv is added to the database. But my next csv contains this:

```
order_id  quantity price order_date shipping_date
2         120      2.00  2016-10-8  2016-10-10
```

A new row must be added. No problem, my query is fine. But the row with order_id 1 is gone at the csv. That row must be deleted from the database. How can I do this? Is this possible to do with my query? Or do I need another one?

Comment: Have you tried adding a trigger so that when the csv is modified you delete whatever was deleted in the csv?  You could do it using any language periodically and hashing the csv and comparing it with last hash,  if it's different scan for differences

Comment: No, because I dont know what the best approach is. I can loop through the csv and check if there are rows in the db and not in the csv. But is that smart, are there better ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a field to store "version" of your update.

```
ALTER  TABLE test_table ADD version BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
```

Before doing INSERT , assign $vers = time() in PHP.
Old rows will contain version value smaller than current version number.

Change your SQL to update `version` field in both INSERT and ON DUPLICATE parts of your query.

```
INSERT INTO test_table (`id`,`order_id`,`quantity`,`price`,`order_date`,`shipping_date`,`version`)
                    VALUES ('$orderId', '$quantity', '$price', '$orderDate', '$shippingDate','$vers')
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `order_date` = '$orderDate', `shipping_date` = '$shippingDate', `version` = $vers"
```

Do import.

Then after import is completed, delete old data

```
DELETE FROM test_table WHERE version < $vers
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: That is really smart! Thank you!

Comment: This is very smart indeed but it also sounds like a common approach. What is the popular name of this method?